# Code Compilation Fails on Linux, Succeeds on Windows: Cause/Fix?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compilation

I have some c++ code that will compile fine in Visual Studio 2013 but will not compile in linux using g++ (no IDE).

What is causing the difference and how can I make the code compile on linux? Is it because they are different compilers? Do I need a specific compiler setting?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef class IApp;
typedef class Component;

class Component
{
public:

protected:
    IApp* app;

    template<typename T>
    void registerEvent()
    {
        app->logEvent();
    }
};

class IApp : protected Component
{
public:
    static IApp NULL_APP;

    void logEvent()
    {
        printf("Event Logged\n");
    }

protected:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("Alive\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

On windows I get no compiler errors. On linux I get the following compiler errors:

```
g++ - o res main.cpp - std = c++11
main.cpp:3 : 15 : warning : ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration[enabled by default]
typedef class IApp;
^
main.cpp:4 : 15 : warning : ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration[enabled by default]
typedef class Component;
^
main.cpp: In member function ‘void Component::registerEvent()’ :
main.cpp : 16 : 6 : error : invalid use of incomplete type ‘class IApp’
app->logEvent();
^
main.cpp:3 : 15 : error : forward declaration of ‘class IApp’
typedef class IApp;
^
main.cpp: At global scope :
main.cpp : 23 : 14 : error : cannot declare variable ‘IApp::NULL_APP’ to be of abstract type ‘IApp’
static IApp NULL_APP;
^
main.cpp:20 : 7 : note : because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘IApp’ :
class IApp : protected Component
    ^
    main.cpp : 31 : 15 : note : virtual void IApp::foo()
    virtual void foo() = 0;
^
make: ***[all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here  you should simply remove `typedef`:

```
typedef class IApp;
```

Then this template method should be defined out-of-line, below `IApp`:

```
template<typename T>
void registerEvent()
{
    app->logEvent();
}
```

Otherwise, it doesn't see the declaration of `IApp` which it needs to dereference.

Finally, this does not make sense:

```
virtual void foo() = 0;
```

Because the same class has a `static` member of its own class type, so needs to instantiate it.  But you've prevented that with a pure virtual function.

GCC is right not to compile this code.

Answer (score 1):

Leave out the typedef keywords before the forward class declarations, they're not necessary. Just class MyClass; is sufficient for a forward declaration. The other issue is that foo() is pure virtual - you need to implement it if you want to instantiate the class. I'm surprised the Microsoft complier doesn't complain but then that's Microsoft.